# Managing multiple viewcontrollers with views displayed in a sequential way - should I use NavigationController?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios

I have a number of viewControllers (iPad) that manage different views presenting various screens to the user (start screen -> settings screen -> main screen -> details screen -> summary screen).
Those screens are being traversed sequentially (as arrows above indicate) based on user interaction.One exception to that rule is that I should be able to navigate to start screen from every other screen.
I dont want to allow a user to explicitly navigate through those screens (using navigationbar) - only app logic should do that.

How should I handle such viewControllers presentation logic? Should i use NavigationController with navBar hidden and pop/push viewcontrollers on it? Or is it an unnecessary overkill? Maybe simply adding viewController.view to subviews of root view will be enough?
Sorry if the question is silly but i think i still didint get MVC in iOS quite right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, NavigationController is your friend in this type of scenario.  The basics are:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newViewController animated:YES];
```

...to add each subsequent view controller on to the stack, and ...

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

...to get you back to the start screen.

And it is certainly possible to hide the navigationBar in your `viewDidLoad` method of each view controller, however this will prevent you from being able to go back in the stack.  If that is intentional, then I think it's a perfectly valid set up.